# SQL SUM + Not working as Should

Tags: sql, ms-access, sum

I have a access db hooked up to a classic asp page.
It should add the value from 2 columns however rather than adding it is joining the data together.
Ie `1 + 1` is showing as `11` not `2`

```
SELECT (desc_1_amnt + desc_2_amnt) AS Sum
FROM Sales_data
```

If I use the `-` sign or the `*` sign it work fine. Just does not seem to add up.

Comment: What are the datatypes of `desc_1_amnt` and `desc_2_amnt`? I'm assuming they're of the textual type.

Comment: They are just numeric values

Comment: Dave Zych thank you. Datatype was set to text changed to number.

Answer (score 1):

The `+` operator adds numeric values but concatenates string values.

Here is an example from the Immediate window.

```vb
? 1 + 1
 2 
? "1" + "1"
11
```

The likely explanation is that your `desc_1_amnt` and `desc_2_amnt` fields are text datatype.  In that case you can cast the text values to numbers before adding them.

```sql
SELECT (Val(desc_1_amnt) + Val(desc_2_amnt)) AS [Sum]
```

Answer (score 1):

The + operator can either be an [arithmetic addition](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178565.aspx) or [string concatenation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177561.aspx).  From your question, it sounds like the "11" result means that the data types are some sort of text instead of numeric.

Changing the columns to a numeric type should give you the results you expect.  Alternately, you could convert the text to numbers using [`CAST` or `CONVERT`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928%28v=sql.110%29.aspx).